# The module called msvcrt causes Blender crashing even if it does existing in Python list

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

My goal is to simplify and create my own version of ***screencast key*** addon and this is my baby-stepping. What I'm doing here is to display a key on the screen that user pressed. However, the module `msvcrt` causes Blender crashing.

Some people uses `bge` or `keyboard` modules for detecting pressed keys but somewhat reason I have no modules in my Python 3. So I decided using `msvcrt` instead which is already exists on the module list.

I searched my problem on Google but sadly couldn't get an accepted solutions.

Any ideas?

This is the code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "KeyPad",
    "author" : "anon",
    "description" : "",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "location" : "",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

import bpy, blf, msvcrt

class Ksys:
    defaults = {
        "id": 0,
        "handler": None,
        "count": 3,
        "color": [255, 255, 255],
        "size": [50, 72],
        "position": {
            "left": [2, 80, 0],
            "center": [],
            "right": []
        }
    }
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                key = msvcrt.getch()
                print("Key Pressing detected!:", key)
             
                Ksys.defaults["handler"] = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw(key), (None, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
                print("Key Assigning detected!")
                
                print("Waiting for 3 seconds then remove the handler on the window")
                bpy.app.timers.register(self.remove(Ksys.defaults["handler"]), Ksys.defaults["count"])

    def draw(key):
        blf.size(Ksys.defaults["id"], Ksys.defaults["size"][0], Ksys.defaults["size"][1])
        blf.color(Ksys.defaults["id"], Ksys.defaults["color"][0], Ksys.defaults["color"][1], Ksys.defaults["color"][2])
        blf.draw(Ksys.defaults["id"], key)

    def remove(key):
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(key, 'WINDOW')

# test run before register
o = Ksys()

def register():
    pass  

def unregister():
    pass
```

Comment: are u using windows?

Comment: @Chris Yes. I'm using Windows. Windows 10.

Comment: @Christ I have Mac also but `msvcrt` is the module that only avaliable on Windows (at least not one of default modules of Python I guess). So I'm currently using Windows.

Comment: that's why i asked...i am using mac too and there is no such module ;)

Comment: It's not crashing, you're just stuck in an infinite loop because of `while True:`

Comment: From my experience it's next to impossible to run a logic separately from Blender's main logic loops. You'll have to use a modal operator I think. Keep in mind autosave is disabled when a modal operator is running though. learnt it the hard way :)

Comment: `msvcrt` is part of the Microsoft C++ runtime library and it's very much not recommended to use it raw, mostly because the code is not portable. `bge` is a Blender module for the game engine, which was removed when the game engine was. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3466/42221) talks about doing kbd input with a modal operator. There are threads on how to do it with a separate blender thread but that's pretty hard to get right as Gorgious pointed out.

Comment: see [the gotchas section on threads](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-when-using-the-threading-module) for comments on threading in the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this in Blender.  The recommended portable way is to create a modal operator.  [Modal Operators](https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists/5ee23daa2b34cbd30bc60295/) is a good free tutorial and [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3466/42221) gives a minimal implementation that I quote here.

```
class VIEW3D_OT_process_input(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Process input while Control key is pressed."""
    bl_idname = 'view3d.process_input'
    bl_label = 'Process Input'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'ESC':
        return {'FINISHED'}
    elif event.ctrl:
        pass # Input processing code.

    return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

There are two obvious limitations of using the keypress event

1. Being modal means that everything else has to wait while the modal operator is running.  Sometimes this is a good thing, often it is not.
2. You only get to receive the key press events that the blender interface is willing to expose and the [list](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html#bpy.types.Event.type) is far from complete.

The second approach has the disadvantage of being much harder to implement properly and much harder to debug.  It also requires writing a version to interface with each OS that the script will run on. See [Threading Gotchas](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-when-using-the-threading-module) for some examples of problems using separate threads.  It also doesn't resolve the second problem.

Unless you have a compelling need to dive into one of the harder parts of OS interface, I would strongly advise using the modal approach.

Comment: Sorry for late response and thank you for details.

Comment: No problem on the late response.  I'm just glad the answer helped you.